# Wrapping arithmetic types in C++

Tags: c++, templates, operators

C++ is awesome, but you cannot inherit from arithmetic types, which, sometimes, would be useful. I wrote the following:

```
template <typename type> class arithmetic
{
    static_assert(std :: is_arithmetic <type> :: value, "Please provide an arithmetic type.");

    // Members

    type _value;

public:

    // Constructors

    inline arithmetic() = default;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline arithmetic(const rtype &);

    // Arithmetic operators

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator + (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator - (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator * (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator / (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator % (const rtype &) const;

    inline auto operator + () const;
    inline auto operator - () const;

    inline auto operator ++ ();
    inline auto operator ++ (int);

    inline auto operator -- ();
    inline auto operator -- (int);

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator = (const rtype &);

    // Comparison operators

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator == (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator != (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator > (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator < (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator >= (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator <= (const rtype &) const;

    // Logical operators

    inline auto operator ! () const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator && (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator || (const rtype &) const;

    // Bitwise operators

    inline auto operator ~ () const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator & (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator | (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator ^ (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator << (const rtype &) const;

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator >> (const rtype &) const;

    // Compound assignment operators

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator += (const rtype &);

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator -= (const rtype &);

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator *= (const rtype &);

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator /= (const rtype &);

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator %= (const rtype &);

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator &= (const rtype &);

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator |= (const rtype &);

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator ^= (const rtype &);

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator <<= (const rtype &);

    template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> inline auto operator >>= (const rtype &);

    // Member and pointer operators

    inline type * operator & ();
    inline const type * operator & () const;

    // Casting

    inline operator type & ();
    inline operator const type & () const;
};

// Constructors

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline arithmetic <type> :: arithmetic(const rtype & value) : _value(value)
{
}

// Arithmetic operators

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator + (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value + rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator - (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value - rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator * (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value * rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator / (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value / rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator % (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value % rvalue;
}

template <typename type> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator + () const
{
    return +(this->_value);
}

template <typename type> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator - () const
{
    return -(this->_value);
}

template <typename type> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator ++ ()
{
    return ++(this->_value);
}

template <typename type> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator ++ (int)
{
    return (this->_value)++;
}

template <typename type> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator -- ()
{
    return --(this->_value);
}

template <typename type> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator -- (int)
{
    return (this->_value)++;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator = (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value = rvalue;
}

// Comparison operators

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator == (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value == rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator != (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value != rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator > (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value > rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator < (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value < rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator >= (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value >= rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator <= (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value <= rvalue;
}

// Logical operators

template <typename type> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator ! () const
{
    return !(this->_value);
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator && (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value && rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator || (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value || rvalue;
}

// Bitwise operators

template <typename type> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator ~ () const
{
    return ~(this->_value);
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator & (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value & rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator | (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value | rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator ^ (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value ^ rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator << (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value << rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator >> (const rtype & rvalue) const
{
    return this->_value >> rvalue;
}

// Compound assignment operators

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator += (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value += rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator -= (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value -= rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator *= (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value *= rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator /= (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value /= rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator %= (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value %= rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator &= (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value &= rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator |= (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value |= rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator ^= (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value ^= rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator <<= (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value <<= rvalue;
}

template <typename type> template <typename rtype, typename std :: enable_if <__arithmetic :: __is_arithmetic_convertible <rtype> :: value> :: type *> inline auto arithmetic <type> ::  operator >>= (const rtype & rvalue)
{
    return this->_value >>= rvalue;
}

// Member and pointer operators

template <typename type> inline type * arithmetic <type> :: operator & ()
{
    return &(this->_value);
}

template <typename type> inline const type * arithmetic <type> :: operator & () const
{
    return &(this->_value);
}

// Casting

template <typename type> inline arithmetic <type> :: operator type & ()
{
    return this->_value;
}

template <typename type> inline arithmetic <type> :: operator const type & () const
{
    return this->_value;
}
```

Which is basically just a very pedantic wrapper for arithmetic types. The wrapper has an arithmetic member called `_value`, then all the calls to any operator are forwarded down to `_value`, and there is a cast operator to the original arithmetic type.

Now, I wonder, is there any circumstance in which, say, an `arithmetic <int>` will behave differently than an `int`? I can't seem to figure out any, but I thought I'd ask a more informed opinion.

On the other hand, if this works as expected and `arithmetic <int>` behaves as an `int`, then why isn't this part of the standard? It looks quite trivial to implement and would allow us to extend arithmetic types as we please.

Comment: You have a lots of methods that should return `arithmetic_type<...>&` or `arithmetic_type` but instead returns value of the underlying type.

Comment: In what way would you want to "extend arithmetic types"? Imagine `std::arithmetic` is available - what exactly do you think it would be good for?

Comment: I may be daft as a brick today, but I can't think of any situation where extending arithmetic types would be useful.

Comment: :) As an example, I am currently working on an `optional <type>` template that I would like to behave as `type`, with the exception that it offers some kind of `bool exists()` that returns if the optional is set or not. I would like to be able to do some kind of `optional <int>` without having to do `my_optional.get_my_int()` every single time.

Answer (score 3):

One issue off the top - no more than one user-defined conversion in an implicit conversion sequence. Consider:

```
class C { C(int); };
void f(C);

f(42);  // works, calls f(C(42));
f(arithmetic<int>(42));  // wouldn't work.
```

Another issue - template specializations:

```
template <typename T> void f(T) { std::cout << "Generic"; }
template <> void f<int>(int) { std::cout << "Specialized"; }

f(42);  // calls specialized
f(arithmetic<int>(42));  // calls generic
```

Closer to home - you can use `arithmetic<int>` but not `arithmetic<arithmetic<int>>`. More generally, various template metaprogramming techniques would be able to tell the difference.

Comment: But this can be fixed, right? Consider the following: `template <typename ctype, typename std :: enable_if <std :: is_convertible <type, ctype> :: value> :: type * = nullptr> operator ctype & ()
    {
        return ctype(this->_value);
    }`. I tried it and it works! Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: This returns a reference to an already-destroyed temporary. Any attempt to actually use such reference exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: You are right. Is this fixed if I remove the reference?

Comment: What if `C` doesn't have a copy-constructor? Make it `f(const C&)`.

Comment: This also turns implicit conversion into explicit one, and would be able to invoke `explicit` constructor where one wouldn't be invoked before. In my example, if `C(int)` is made explicit, then `f(42)` wouldn't compile but `f(arithmetic<int>(42))` would, I think (with your "convert-to-anything" operator added).

Comment: One more issue with this implementation (only because I just ran into it!): a regular && or || will short circuit, but an overloaded one will not.

Answer (score 0):

Anywhere an int type is explicitly expected but `arithmetic<int>` wrapper is provided, you should be concerned. Defining implicit conversions will help this in some cases, but won't help where any of the following are involved:

- int references. A `f(int&)` cannot receive an `arithmetic<int>&`. Also, here, converting your object to an in will lead to a temporary variable being modified, not your original object. Function of the `f(int const&)` can reasonably by expected to behave well, since you should expect the function to not hold onto the reference (but its not guaranteed).  Generally speaking, you'll also get more mileage out of implicit conversions if your ints and objects are treated as immutable variables.
- int pointers. For the same reason. An `int*` is not a `arithmetic<int>*`
- int arrays. An `arithmetic<int>[]` cannot be supplied where an int[] is explicitly required.
- any template type of int. A `vector<arithmetic<int>>` cannot be used where a `vector<int>` is required.
- A `F<arithmetic<int>>` cannot be provided where `F<T>` has specialization for `F<int>` but not for the generic case *and* you're prevented from providing your own specialization (hmm... is this possible? For example, by defining all known specialization privately in a .cxx).

Also, instantiating F where F declares. If your class is truly an arithmetic type, you must also be able to declare `arithmetic<int>`. In your example:

```
static_assert(std :: is_arithmetic <type> :: value, "Please provide an arithmetic type.");
```

will cause it to fail. (Unless you specialize is_arithmetic> for all T.)